# Correlation coefficient from randomised variables in R

Tags: r, random, correlation

my goal is to get a new variable of correlation (spearman's) coefficents where each number corresponds to the correlation between two randomised variables.

e.g.

```
var1=c(1, 2, 3, 0, 2)
var2=c(3, 6, 0, 1, 2)
```

I've tried

```
set.seed(1)
f1=numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:10000) {rand <- replicate(10000, sample(var1))
 rand1 <- replicate(10000, sample(var2))
 f1[i]=cor(rand, rand1, use ="everything", method=c("spearman"))
 }
```

which gives me this message: Warning message:
In f1[i]=cor(rand, rand1, use = "everything", method = c("spearman")) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I tried this:

```
cof <- cor((replicate(1000, sample(var1))), (replicate(1000, sample(var2))), use ="everything", method=c("spearman"))
```

which returns a matrix of correlation coefficients for each value, not each variable

Alternatively, if there's a way to ask R to correlate e.g. row 1 in one data frame with row 1 in another, then on to rows 2 then rows 3 etc I can get matrices of just my randomised variables with this:

```
set.seed(1)
f1=numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:10000) {rand <- replicate(10000, sample(var1))
  rand1 <- replicate(10000, sample(var2))
  }
```

which I would then have to correlate with each other

is there a way to calculate the correlation coefficient between each pair of randomised variables as they are generated and then create a new variable made up of the correlation coefficients for each randomisation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be easier for you to just use the actual spearman correlation formula, without using cor().

This would look like this:

```
spearman<-function(x,y){
  X<-as.matrix(x)
  Y<-as.matrix(y)
  y<-rowSums(X)
  a<-rowSums(Y)
  spearman<-2*cor(y,a)/(1+cor(y,a))
  return(spearman)
}
```

After running this, you could then use

```
spearman(data1$firstrow,data2$secondrow)
```

to calculate the desired correlations.

And then I guess you could use a sort of loop like this:

```
for (i in nrow(dat)) {
  for (i in nrow(dat)) {
  correlation<-spearman(datmat[i,],datmat2[i,])
  print(correlation[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you tried to do.
Maybe this will solve your problem :

```
var1=c(1, 2, 3, 0, 2)
var2=c(3, 6, 0, 1, 2)

set.seed(1)
n=100
rand <- replicate(n, sample(var1))
rand1 <- replicate(n, sample(var2))

# That is maybe what you are searching for
f1 <- apply(rand,2,cor,rand1)
```

You would have a *n x n* matrix with each *( i , j )* representing the correlation between *i*th column of rand and *j*th column of rand1.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, it seems your `rand` and `rand1` matrices have 5 rows and many columns, and you would like to correlate each column from `rand` with the equivalent column from `rand1`? If I got that right, you could use `cor.test` to get the spearman rank correlation, e.g. in a loop. Since that is relatively slow, you could also rewrite the formula for Spearman rank correlation in vectorized form and use that (see below). If you are interested in row-wise correlations it is easy to adjust or transpose the matrices.

```r
var1=c(1, 2, 3, 0, 2)
var2=c(3, 6, 0, 1, 2)
set.seed(1)
n=10000
rand <- replicate(n, sample(var1))
rand1 <- replicate(n, sample(var2))

library(matrixStats)
colwiseSpearman <- function(m1, m2, correct=TRUE){
    require(matrixStats)
    n <- dim(m1)[2]
    l <- dim(m1)[1]
    if (correct){
        Txy <- t(sapply(seq_len(n), function(x){
            t0 <- tabulate(rand[,x])
            t1 <- tabulate(rand1[,x])
            return(c(Tx=sum(t0^3-t0)/12, Ty=sum(t1^3-t1)/12))
        }))
        return(((l^3-l)/6 - rowSums((colRanks(rand, ties.method="average")-colRanks(rand1, ties.method="average"))^2) - Txy[,1] - Txy[,2])/sqrt(((l^3-l)/6 - 2*Txy[,1])*((l^3-l)/6 - 2*Txy[,2]))) # Spearman cor.coeff. corrected for ties 
    } else {
        return(1-(6*rowSums((colRanks(rand, ties.method="average")-colRanks(rand1, ties.method="average"))^2) / (l^3-l)))}
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a=colwiseSpearman(rand, rand1),
               b=as.numeric(sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) cor.test(rand[,x], rand1[,x], method="spearman")$estimate)), times=10L )
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval cld
#>     a   65.47719   68.06543   74.83393   69.2682   72.90266  109.9133    10  a 
#>     b 2769.97084 2789.39907 2826.01399 2821.6867 2849.08012 2880.5115    10   b
a <- colwiseSpearman(rand, rand1)
b <- as.numeric(sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) cor.test(rand[,x], rand1[,x], method="spearman")$estimate))
all.equal(a, b)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>